# How to share data between steps in squish

Tags: python, qt, squish

I have feature file with same steps on different pages.

```
Feature: Wizard

    Install wizard.

    Scenario: 1. Installing application.  
        Given App launch
        When Next button selected
        Then page1 is displayed
        When Next button selected
        Then page2 is displayed
        When Next button selected
        Then page3 is displayed
        When Next button selected
```

How can pass my current page to **When Next button selected** function

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/tutorials-qt.html#tut-bdd-qt-sharing), you can use the `context` of step definitions:

```
@Given("App launch")
def step(context):
    context={}
    context["currentpage"] = "current page info here"

@When("Next button selected")
def step(context):
    step = context["currentpage"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Squish documentation recommends limiting your use of "context" to the userData key.  I believe this is because some newer versions publish information to the context object (context.text is the step title, etc).

So, in your OnScenarioStart hook, you can setup your context object...

```
@OnScenarioStart
def hook(context):
    context.userData = {}
```

Similar to the other answer here, your steps would look like this..

```
@Given("App launch")
def step(context):
    # assuming page variable has your page content
    context.userData['page'] = page

@When("Next button selected")
def step(context):
    page = context.userData['page']
```